# Learning linux networking stack

Tags: linux-kernel

I am planning to dive into the Linux TCP/IP stack. Which kernel version source tree should i be looking into - it should be closer to the current kernel code in concepts but a bit easier to grasp and understand. Or should i be looking into other projects like lwip.

My aim is to learn everything about networking above the device driver level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lwip` is a good thing to start with. It is a very simple implementation of the basic functionality. Moreover you could easily make two 'virtual hosts' in the user space to see it in action - just create two processes that talk to each other over pipe, for example. This way you get the basic understanding. Then you definitely should look at modern `linux` code.

Answer (score 1):

One advise that i got from a network programmer is to start looking at kernel 1.0 source first and then gradually use latest 3.X kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

Install a recent linux distribution (Ubuntu, for example), and see which kernel version it uses by executing the `uname -r` command. Download the version this command shows.

The first step in linux kernel compilation is the configuration setup. By downloading the same kernel version of the one installed with your distribution, you will be able to run `make oldconfig` and import all of these configurations with no pain, so you can focus on learning the network stack implementation.